# Is a facet always a maximal area section of a simplex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $T\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed simplex, $H\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a variable affine hyperplane. Is it true that the maximal area (i.e. the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume) of $T\cap H$ is attained when $H$ contains a facet of $T$?

Comment: In case someone is trying to prove this and at some point needs that for any vector $v$, the interval $\{\langle x,v\rangle;x\in T\}$ achieves minimal length when $v$ is perpendicular to some face: that is not true (consider the $3$-simplex with vertices $(1,0,0.01),(-1,0,0.01),(0,1,-0.01),(0,-1,-0.01)$)

Comment: @Saul In other words, the width of a simplex is not its shortest height. Yes, it is not, even for a regular simplex.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there is a $5$-dimensional simplex with a hyperplane section which is larger than any of its facets, see [Walkup, A simplex with a large cross-section, Am. Math. Monthly, January 1968](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2315102.pdf).
The idea is to squeeze a regular 5-simplex along the common perpendicular of two opposite 2-dimensional faces. The volume of the mid-section between these faces does not change, but it turns out that all facets become smaller than this cross-section if the scaling coefficient is small enough.

For more information see also the [PhD thesis of Dirksen](https://d-nb.info/1082537128/34).

Comment: Thank you Vanya! The Dirksen's thesis also contains the information that for a regular simplex the claim is true.